# Cant send file via email while using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, file, email, android-fileprovider

Good day! I got a problem while sending file via email (im using FileProvider)
from code below everything only works when i do not attaching file
When Im uncommenting emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri) line nothing crashes sending form appears but nothing sends to the given adress
Maybe im missing something, please help.

```
File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getCacheDir(), "test.txt");

    if (file.exists() == false);
    file.mkdirs();

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(MainActivity.this.openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
        outputStreamWriter.write(values.get(i)+"\n");
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }

     Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,AUTHORITY,file);
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "test@gmail.com" });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[] {});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "FROM Sample");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HI");

 //  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    MainActivity.this.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

FileProvider

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="app.testapp"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<files-path
    name="my_images"
    path="images/" />

<files-path
    name="my_docs"
    path="docs/" />

<external-files-path
    name="external_files_dir"
    path="/" />

<cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="/" />

<external-cache-path
    name="external_cache_dir"
    path="/" />

<external-media-path
    name="external_media_dir"
    path="/" />

<external-media-path
    name="external_media_dir"
    path="/" />
```

Comment: `file.mkdirs();` You have made a directory instead of a file with that name. Remove statement en delete directory.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) ` You will get that exception. You should display a toast to inform the user. And stop/return.